# Design pattern for method returning different types/classes

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

This is a question for the Object Design Pattern specialists.

Let's assume I have a `Parser` class that is in charge of reading/parsing a stream of data (that carry information **packets of different types**). Each of these packets carry a different type of information, so ideally I would have a class for each type of packet (`PacketTypeA`, `PacketTypeB`, ... each one with its own interface).

```
class Parser {

public:

    /* ctor */
    /* dtor */


   void read_packet(/* arguments */);

   // methods...
private:
   // more methods...
}
```

The method `Parser::read_packet` would then go through the stream and return a class (or pointer or reference to a class) to the appropriate packet type.

Would you use void pointers for this? How about a generic class (`PacketBasicInterface`) that would provide a common (partial) interface to query about the type of packet (so that any decision could then be made at runtime)?

```
// Pure virtual (abstract) class to provide a common (and partial) interface
class PacketBasicInterface {
public:

    std::string whoAmI() const = 0;
    bool amIofType(const std::string& type) const = 0;

}

// Class to access data of type A packet
class PacketTypeA : public PacketBasicInterface {

public:
    // methodA_1()
    // methodA_2(), ...
}

// Class to access data of type A packet
class PacketTypeB : public PacketBasicInterface {

public:
    // methodB_1()
    // methodB_2(), ...
}
```

Any thought or feedback would be very much appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need, but some sort of abstract factory, or composite?

Answer (score 5):

This is what [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is for.

I would define an enumeration class, that enumerates all possible packet types:

```
enum class packet_type {initialization_packet, confirmation_type, ... };
```

And have `read_packet` return a tuple of packet_type and a variant:

```
typedef std::variant< ... > packet_info;

std::tuple<packet_type, packet_info> read_packet();
```

Don't really need a formal enumeration, but it makes it easier to figure out what to do with the variant.

A few variations on this general approach include:

1. Using an opaque `std::string`, rather than a fixed enumeration, to specify the packet type.
2. Using `std::any` instead of a formal `std::variant`.
3. Instead of using a simple enumeration, or an opaque token like a `std::string`, use a slightly non-trivial class to define the packet type, with the class's methods taking the variant metadata as parameters, and encapsulating the operations that can be done on the packet.

Of course, as noted in the cited link, `std::variant` requires C++17. Which would be a good argument for you to update your compiler: you get a simple way to implement a completely type-safe approach.

Comment: This isn't a Object Design Pattern.

Comment: @SantlagoVarela indeed, it's much better

Comment: It might perform better, it might be more optimal, but is it more maintainable, readable and cohesive as an adequate Design Pattern? It's a good solution, but it still doesn't fit the tag "design patterns" and Object Oriented Approach.

Comment: +1 Because imo this is the modern C++ solution to such a problem. (and until C++17 is ubiquitous there’s `boost::variant`). The only thing I’d like to see added is an example of `std::variant::visit` or `boost::variant::apply_visitor`. Imo that is the more natural way to handle the different types in a variant. It’s also slightly less error prone because you do not have to match enumerator to type manually.

Answer (score 1):

> Would you use void pointers for this?

No.

> How about a generic class (PacketBasicInterface) that would provide a common (partial) interface to query about the type of packet (so that any decision could then be made at runtime)?

<strike>That makes most sense to me.</strike>

Let me refine that. Yes, it will be good to have a generic base class. However, when parsing the stream to construct sub-types of the base class, don't rely on an `if-else` type approach. Rather, use a factory pattern. Let the various factories construct the right object types based an on a *key*, which I assume will be available from the data being parsed.

If you encounter the string `"PacketTypeA"` in your data, you would expect that `PacketTypeAFactory` will be responsible for constructing the object.

FWIW, this approach is scalable for lots of sub-types of the base class. We use this approach at my work and it has served us well for over twenty years.

---

Here's the skeletal structure of the code base I am thinking of:

---

The classes.

```
class PacketBasicInterface { };

class PacketTypeA : public PacketBasicInterface { };

class PacketTypeB : public PacketBasicInterface { };
```

---

The interface of the factory.

```
// PacketFactory.h
class PacketFactory
{
   public:

      static PacketBasicInterface* makePacket(std::string const& packetData);

      static void registerFactory(std::string const& key, PacketFactory* factory);

      virtual PacketBasicInterface* make(std::string const& packetData) = 0;

      virtual ~PacketFactory() {}
};
```

---

Implementation of the framework that makes the factory work.

```
// PacketFactory.cpp

#include "PacketFactory.h"

namespace PacketBasicInterface_Impl
{
   using PacketFactoryMap = std::map<std::string, PacketFactory*>;

   PacketFactoryMap& getPacketFactoryMap()
   {
      static PacketFactoryMap theMap;
      return theMap;
   }
};

uisng namespace PacketBasicInterface_Impl;

PacketBasicInterface* PacketFactory::makePacket(std::string const& packetData)
{
   std::string key = extractKey(packetData);
   PacketFactoryMap& theMap = getPacketFactoryMap();
   PacketFactoryMap::iterator iter = theMap.find(key);
   if ( iter == theMap.end() )
   {
      return nullptr;
   }

   return iter->second->make(packetData);
}

void registerFactory(std::string const& key, PacketFactory* factory)
{
   getPacketFactoryMap()[key] = factory;
}
```

---

Code for making objects of type PacketTypeA using the factory pattern.

```
// PacketTypeAFactory.cpp

#include "PacketFactory.h"
#include "PacketTypeA.h"

class PacketTypeAFactory : public PacketFactory
{
   public:

      virtual PacketBasicInterface* make(std::string const& packetData)
      {
         PacketTypeA* packet = new PacketTypeA();

         // Flesh out packet with data pulled from packetData
         // ...
         //

         return packet;
      }

      struct Initializer
      {
         Initializer() { PacketFactory::registerFactory("PacketTypeA", new PacketTypeAFactory); }
      };
};


// Constructing this object at static initialization time makes sure
// that PacketTypeAFactory is registered with PacketFactory when the
// stream data need to be parsed.
static PacketTypeAFactory::Initializer initializer;
```

---

The code for making objects of type PacketTypeB is very similar to the
 code for making objects of type PacketTypeA using the factory pattern.

```
// PacketTypeBFactory.cpp


#include "PacketFactory.h"
#include "PacketTypeB.h"

class PacketTypeBFactory : public PacketFactory
{
   public:

      virtual PacketBasicInterface* make(std::string const& packetData)
      {
         PacketTypeA* packet = new PacketTypeA();

         // Flesh out packet with data pulled from packetData
         // ...
         //

         return packet;
      }

      struct Initializer
      {
         Initializer() { PacketFactory::registerFactory("PacketTypeB", new PacketTypeBFactory); }
      };
};


// Constructing this object at static initialization time makes sure
// that PacketTypeBFactory is registered with PacketFactory when the
// stream data need to be parsed.
static PacketTypeBFactory::Initializer initializer;
```

---

Client code.

```
std::string packetData;
while ( getPacketData(packetData) )
{
   PacketBasicInterface* packet = PacketFactory::makePacket(packetData);
   if ( packet == nullptr )
   {
      // Deal with error.
   }
   else
   {
      // Use packet
   }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't double dispatching be a cleaner and more object oriented approach than having an _interface to query about the type of packet_? I mean, using polymorphism and having such a method smells a bit, doesn't it? What's the purpose? Is it to use `dynamic_cast` when you find a match? Doh!!

Comment: @skypjack, good points. I updated the answer. Hopefully that makes more sense to all.

Comment: Absolutely. Meanwhile I added my own answer for nobody explicitly mentioned double dispatching and the question is tagged _design-patterns_. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Double dispatching can be the way to go if you are looking for a design pattern from the realm of object oriented programming.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct Visitor;

struct PacketBasicInterface {
    virtual void accept(Visitor &) = 0;
};

struct PacketTypeA: PacketBasicInterface {
    void accept(Visitor &) override;
};

struct PacketTypeB: PacketBasicInterface {
    void accept(Visitor &) override;
};

struct Visitor {
    void visit(PacketTypeA) {
        std::cout << "PacketTypeA" << std::endl;
    }

    void visit(PacketTypeB) {
        std::cout << "PacketTypeB" << std::endl;
    }
};

void PacketTypeA::accept(Visitor &visitor) {
    visitor.visit(*this);
}

void PacketTypeB::accept(Visitor &visitor) {
    visitor.visit(*this);
}

struct Parser {
   PacketBasicInterface * read_packet() {
       return new PacketTypeB{};
   }
};

int main() {
    Visitor visitor;
    auto *packet = Parser{}.read_packet();
    packet->accept(visitor);
    delete packet;
}
```